# Given $dy/dt = 6y/39 -(y^2)/2002$ and the point $(0,14)$, what is the original equation in "$y=\dots$" form?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is how I tried to solve it:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{6y}{39}-\frac{y^2}{2002}$$
I multiplied and divided:
$$\frac{dy}{\frac{6y}{39}-\frac{y^2}{2002}}=dt$$
I simplified:
$$\frac{dy}{\frac{2y}{13}-\frac{y^2}{2002}}=dt$$
I found a common denominator:
$$\frac{dy}{\frac{308y-y^2}{2002}}=dt$$
I divided the fractions:
$$\frac{2002dy}{308y-y^2}=dt$$
I completed the square:
$$\frac{2002dy}{308y-y^2-154^2+154^2}=dt$$
$$\frac{2002dy}{-(y^2-308y+154^2)+154^2}=dt$$
$$\frac{2002dy}{-(y-154)^2+154^2}=dt$$
Now I am temporarily looking at only the left side of the equation to find the integral:
$$\int\frac{2002}{-(y-154)^2+154^2}dy$$
I substituted u:
$$2002\int\frac{1}{(-1)(u)^2+154^2}du$$
At this point I was very confused so I tried to use arctan when I probably wasn't allowed to. I used the following formula:
$$\int\frac{b}{b^2+a^2x^2}dx=\arctan(\frac{ax}{b})+c$$
My integral:
$$\frac{2002}{154}\int\frac{154}{(-1)(u)^2+154^2}du$$
$$\frac{2002}{154}\arctan(\frac{iu}{154})$$
$$13\arctan(\frac{i(y-154)}{154})$$
The integral of $1dt$ is $t$ so I got this equation:
$$13\arctan(\frac{i(y-154)}{154})=t+c$$
I then solved for y:
$$\frac{i(y-154)}{154}=\tan(\frac{t+c}{13})$$
$$y=\frac{154\tan(\frac{t+c}{13})}{i}+154$$
I then solved for c by substituting the initial point (0,14) into the equation:
$$14=\frac{154\tan(\frac{0+c}{13})}{i}+154$$
$$\frac{-140i}{154}=\tan(\frac{c}{13})$$
$$\arctan(\frac{-10i}{11})=\frac{c}{13}$$
$$c=13\arctan(\frac{-10i}{11})$$
And I substituted the found $c$ value into the equation:
$$y=\frac{154\tan(\frac{t+13\arctan(\frac{-10i}{11})}{13})}{i}+154$$
Is this *technically* correct or did do I something wrong?
If I did do something wrong, what did I do wrong?
What would be an alternative method of solving this?

Comment: Your integral is of the form $\int \frac{1}{a^2 - x^2} dx$ and not $\int \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2} dx$. Thus that integral would be $\frac{1}{2a} \log\left(\frac{a + x}{a -x}\right)$ instead of $\arctan$. And you can obtain that by noting $\int \frac{1}{a^2 - x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2a} \int \left( \frac{1}{a + x} + \frac{1}{a - x} \right) dx$.

Comment: So, for clarification, the full common integral you used is $$\int\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}log(\frac{a+x}{a-x})$$right?

Comment: Yeah. Note that the denominator would be $a - x$.

Comment: I'm going to clarify that the log is ln, or log base e, not log base 10 because I got confused with that.

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$\frac{2002}{308y-y^2}=\frac{2002}{y(308y-y)}=\frac{2002}{308}\bigg(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{308-y}\bigg)=\frac{1001}{154}\bigg(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{308-y}\bigg)$$
and hence
$$\frac{2002dy}{308y-y^2}=dt$$
becomes
$$\frac{1001}{154}\bigg(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{308-y}\bigg)dy=dt.$$
Integrating both sides gives
$$ \frac{1001}{154}\bigg(\ln|y|-\ln|308-y|\bigg)=t+C.$$
So
$$ \ln\bigg|\frac{y}{308-y}\bigg|=\frac{154}{1001}t+C' $$
or
$$ \frac{y}{308-y}=ke^{\frac{154}{1001}t}. $$
From this, you can solve for $y$ to get the answer.

Comment: Ok. Now see the update.

Comment: What I was confused about is how you can go from $\frac{2002}{y(308-y)}$ to $\frac{2002}{308}(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{308-y})$. Is there a rule that says $$\frac{a}{x(b-x)}=\frac{a}{b}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{b-x})$$ because you usually can't break up a denominator that easily

Comment: Also, it kind of confused me at first that it showed $308y-y^2$ factoring out to $y(308y-y)$ so if you could edit it that would be good (I can't because it's a change of only 1 character)

Answer (score 0):

**After getting some feedback I tried to resolve this going back to right after I substituted u:**
$$2002\int\frac{1}{154^2-u^2}du$$
I used the common integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}ln(\frac{a+x}{a-x})$$
And I got:
$$2002(\frac{1}{308}ln(\frac{154+u}{154-u}))=t+c$$
$$ln(\frac{154+u}{154-u})=\frac{2(t+c)}{13}$$
$$\frac{154+u}{154-u}=e^{\frac{2(t+c)}{13}}$$
$$\frac{154+u}{154-u}=e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}*e^{\frac{2(c)}{13}}$$
$10^{\frac{2(c)}{13}}$ can be given the name "A" because it is a constant:
$$\frac{154+y-154}{154-(y-154)}=e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A$$
$$\frac{y}{308-y}=10^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A$$
Multiplying the denominator and distributing:
$$y=(308)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A-(y)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A$$
$$y+(y)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A=(308)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A$$
$$y=\frac{(308)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A}{1+e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A}$$
Then to solve for A I am going back a little to where there was only one A:
$$\frac{y}{308-y}=e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}A$$
I plugged in the point (0,14):
$$\frac{14}{308-14}=e^{\frac{2(0)}{13}}A$$
$$A=\frac{1}{21}$$
I plugged in A to the "y =" equation
$$y=\frac{(308)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}\frac{1}{21}}{1+e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}\frac{1}{21}}$$
$$y=\frac{(44)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}}{3(1+e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}\frac{1}{21})}$$
$$y=\frac{(44)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}}{\frac{21+e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}}{7}}$$
I divided the fractions:
$$y=\frac{(308)e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}}{21+e^{\frac{2(t)}{13}}}$$

Comment: The natural logarithm is to the base $e$, the Euler number, not base $10$.

Comment: No, it's $$y=\frac{308 e^{\frac{2 t}{13}}}{e^{\frac{2 t}{13}}+21}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is also a Bernoulli equation. So set
$$
u=\frac{2}{13y}+\frac1{2002},
$$
then
$$
u'=-\frac{2y'}{13y^2}=-\frac2{13}\left(\frac{2}{13y}+\frac1{2002}\right)=-\frac2{13}u
$$
so that
$$
u(t)=u(0)e^{-\frac2{13}t}.
$$
Now translate back to a formula for $y$.